# how to replace a character in a string and save into text file in c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to replace pipe symbol(|) with new line(\n) in my text(test1.txt) file. But when I'm trying to save it in text(test2.text) file the result is not coming in my test2.txt file but I see the result in my console window. Any one please help on this.

```
    string lines = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\NetProject\Nag Assignments\hi.txt");
    //string input = "abcd|efghijk|lmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    lines = lines.Replace('|', '\n');
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\NetProject\Nag Assignments\hi2.txt", lines);
    Console.WriteLine(lines);
```

Comment: Hi Winney, my text2.txt file is coming without pipe symbol. That means where ever i have pipe symbol it is not going into second line. Sorry I just edited my post. My input text file consists of Alpha numeric values.

Comment: And also is there any way to store the text between two pipe symbels in to string? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want multiple things here. (both original question and subsequent comments)

One is to separate the lines and be able to reference them separately:

```
string[] separatedLines = lines.Split('|');
```

The other is to join them back together with a different separator:

```
string rejoinedLines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, separatedLines);
```

You then have access to the individual lines from the `separatedLines` variable above such as `separatedLines[0]` and you can also write the `rejoinedLines` variable back to the other file like you wanted.

**EDIT**: For example, the following code:

```
string lines = "a|bc|def";
string[] separatedLines = lines.Split('|');
string rejoinedLines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, separatedLines);
for (int i = 0; i < separatedLines.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", i + 1, separatedLines[i]);
}
```

Gives output of:

```
Line 1: a
Line 2: bc
Line 3: def
```

Comment: Hi McAden, I got the 1st answer. But can you help me on how to copy the charectars b/w pipe symbol?

Comment: The text that was previously between the pipes would now be individual entries in the `separatedLines` array.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one:

```
 lines = lines.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
```

It returns `"\r\n"`, for non-Unix platforms according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
lines = lines.Replace('|', '\n');
```

Try:

```
lines = lines.Replace("|","\r\n");
```

Comment: Carriage return comes before the line feed.

Comment: the bove one is not giving me the expected result.

Comment: got it. the carriage return should come before the line fee. Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can you also please help out on how to save these new lined charectares into a string variable. For eg, if I have 3 lines of charectares in my text file, I need to save these 3 lines of charectares in 3 different sting variables.

Comment: You can (should) use Environment.NewLine() which will print the appropriate carriage return character(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] space = lines.Split ('|');
```

Will save every substring in space.

The line break should be `\r\n` for carriage return. It depends if you are reading a file binary or text mode. `\n` is used in text mode while `\r\n` is used in binary mode.